# MIP Ubuntu on Cloud Foundry

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I want to implement a REST service in C# to label files with the help of the MIP SDK. Is it possible to get the Microsoft.InformationProtection.File.Ubuntu1804 SDK to run on Cloud Foundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that the dependencies for Ubuntu SDK are in place and it should be able to run in Cloud Foundry. We've had customers run it successfully in AKS so think it shouldn't be any different in Cloud Foundry.